# How to convert an array [] to a series of { key: value } paired objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, data-manipulation

I'm looking to transform this...

```
[
  [ 'market', 'type', 'timeframe', 'proximal', 'distal', 'risk', 'tradeable' ], // object keys
  [ 'AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE' ] // key values
]
```

into this...

```
[ 
  { 
    market: 'AD', 
    type : 'DZ', 
    timeframe: 'daily', 
    proximal: '0.6375', 
    distal: '0.6283', 
    risk: '$920.00', 
    tradeable: 'FALSE' 
  }
]
```

So far, here's what I have...

```
// each element of the array (I call a 'zone')
data.forEach(z => {

  // each element inside the 'zone'
  z.forEach(e => {

    // headings to object keys, where k = key and v = value
    const obj = headings.reduce((k,v) => (k[v]="",k),{})

    console.log(obj)
  })
})
```

console.log(obj) outputs this to the console:

```
Object {
  distal: "",
  market: "",
  proximal: "",
  risk: "",
  timeframe: "",
  tradeable: "",
  type: ""
}
```

I just cant figure out how to get the values into those key pairs, **PLEASE HELP**!!

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Why would you put the result object as a sole element in an array?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question @Bergi

Comment: Your "*into this...*" desired result has an array literal (`[ … ]`) that I cannot see any need for (and no attempt to create it in your code either)

Comment: Oh I understand @Bergi, because this will be an `array` of objects, I just didn't include the full `data` array in my question for the sake of brevity

Comment: Why an array of objects, your code builds only one? If there were more objects, where would their data come from?

Comment: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a reduce, a reduce runs a function on every element of an array and returns an accumulator each iteration. In this case the starting accumulator is the empty object {}, and on each iteration we add the key to the accumulator with the value coming from the current index in the other array.

```js
const data = [
  [ 'Market', 'Type', 'Timeframe', 'Proximal', 'Distal', 'Risk', 'Tradeable' ],
  [ 'AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE' ],
  [ 'EC', 'SZ', 'daily', '1.13475', '1.13895', '$525.00', 'FALSE' ],
  [ 'DXY', 'DZ', '60 min', '96.85', '96.76', '', 'FALSE' ]
];

const match = (keys, values) => keys.reduce((result, key, index) => {
  result[key] = values[index];
  return result;
}, {});

const matchAll = data => data.reduce((results, current, index) => {
  if (index) {
    results.push(match(data[0], data[index]));
  }
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(matchAll(data));
```

Comment: Why use reduce here- reduce has a specific functionality, and you aren't using it?

Comment: Reduce reduces an array into a result, that is exactly what I am doing here.

Comment: Oh, missed the fact you were using the initial parameter. This is the better solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you @AdrianBrand! If you have the inclination, please could you explain exactly what your code is doing?

Comment: I will add a description to the answer

Comment: Sorry @AdrianBrand, a further enquiry - what's the best way to now iterate over `data`? I have more than one record to perform your code on, like so; `data[1]`...`[2]`... and so on

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: @AdrianBrand, imagine 
`const data = [ 
  [ 'Market', 'Type', 'Timeframe', 'Proximal', 'Distal', 'Risk', 'Tradeable' ],
  [ 'AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE' ],
  [ 'EC', 'SZ', 'daily', '1.13475', '1.13895', '$525.00', 'FALSE' ],
  [ 'DXY', 'DZ', '60 min', '96.85', '96.76', '', 'FALSE' ]
]`

ie: I have multiple records to apply your code to, what's the most succinct way to iterate over them?

Comment: I added another reduce to iterate through the top level array.

Comment: @AdrianBrand thank you my friend, that works perfectly. Happy holidays!

Comment: What a horribly cyptic name 'match'. If I read that I'd think it has something to do with regular expressions. I certainly would have no idea it takes 2 parallel arrays of keys and values and creates an object.

Comment: It is matching keys with their values, it is nowhere near as cryptic as the one character variable names solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try using it like this:

```js
function reinterpret(data) {
  let result = {}
  data[0].forEach((key, index) => {
    result[key] = data[1][index];
  });
  return [result];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rather than using a `reduce`, you could use a simple `forEach`. From what i understand, the index of your first array are map to your second array. So just do something like this.

```js
let arrays = [
  [ 'market', 'type', 'timeframe', 'proximal', 'distal', 'risk', 'tradeable' ], // object keys
  [ 'AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE' ] // key values
]

let output = {};
arrays[0].forEach((item, index) => {
  output[item] = arrays[1][index];
});

console.log([output]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```js
let arrays = [
  ["market", "type", "timeframe", "proximal", "distal", "risk", "tradeable"], // object keys
  ["AD", "DZ", "daily", "0.6375", "0.6283", "$920.00", "FALSE"] // key values
];

const keys = 0;
const values = 1;

const objKeys = arrays[keys].map((item, index) => {
  return { [item]: arrays[values][index] };
});

const obj = [Object.assign({}, ...objKeys)];

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling lots of functions looks elegant but if you care about speed a simple loop is the winner

```js
const arrays =[
  [ 'market', 'type', 'timeframe', 'proximal', 'distal', 'risk', 'tradeable' ], // object keys
  [ 'AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE' ] // key values
];

function parallelArraysToObject([keys, values]) {
  const result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    result[keys[i]] = values[i];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(parallelArraysToObject(arrays));
```

[image]

note: code for fromEntries solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366721/128511), code for reduce solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366555/128511)

and while we're at it here is one that assumes the data is from something like excel with the first row being column names.

```js
const data = [
  [ 'Market', 'Type', 'Timeframe', 'Proximal', 'Distal', 'Risk', 'Tradeable' ],
  [ 'AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE' ],
  [ 'EC', 'SZ', 'daily', '1.13475', '1.13895', '$525.00', 'FALSE' ],
  [ 'DXY', 'DZ', '60 min', '96.85', '96.76', '', 'FALSE' ]
];

const parallelArraysToObject = (keys, values) => {
  const result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    result[keys[i]] = values[i];
  }
  return result;
};

const rowsToArraysOfObjects = data => {
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    results.push(parallelArraysToObject(data[0], data[i]));
  }
  return results;
};

console.log(rowsToArraysOfObjects(data));
```

And the same with the loop unrolled (well, maybe not unrolled but witout the nested function call)

```js
const data = [
  [ 'Market', 'Type', 'Timeframe', 'Proximal', 'Distal', 'Risk', 'Tradeable' ],
  [ 'AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE' ],
  [ 'EC', 'SZ', 'daily', '1.13475', '1.13895', '$525.00', 'FALSE' ],
  [ 'DXY', 'DZ', '60 min', '96.85', '96.76', '', 'FALSE' ]
];

const rowsToArraysOfObjects = data => {
  const results = [];
  const keys = data[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    const values = data[i];
    const record = {};
    for (let j = 1; j < keys.length; ++j) {
      record[keys[j]] = values[j];
    }
    results.push(record);
  }
  return results;
};

console.log(rowsToArraysOfObjects(data));
```

We can see that often in vogue coding styles are not very perf oriented. double reduce is up to 7x slower depending on the browser and at a minimum 25% slower.

[image]

Comment: What did you use to get the cross browser profiling?

Comment: jsperf- most likely launching different browsers himself

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [
    ['market', 'type', 'timeframe', 'proximal', 'distal', 'risk', 'tradeable'], // object keys
    ['AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE'] // key values
]

var result = [];
var obj = {};
arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (arr.indexOf(item) == 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            obj[item[i]] = arr[1][i];
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const kvs =[
  [ 'market', 'type', 'timeframe', 'proximal', 'distal', 'risk', 'tradeable' ], // object keys
  [ 'AD', 'DZ', 'daily', '0.6375', '0.6283', '$920.00', 'FALSE' ] // key values
];

const ob = Object.fromEntries(kvs[0].map((key, ndx) => [key, kvs[1][ndx]]));

console.log(ob);
```

This solution is not the fastest. [A fast solution is a simple loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366910/128511). It's important to know when speed is important. If you're doing this a million times a second then of course you should use the fastest solution. If you're doing it once in a while (like parsing a response from a server when the user clicks "more data") then fastest clearly isn't a priority. On the other hand if you plan on putting the code in a library you should argably use the fastest reasonable solution since you have no idea how the user will user your code. Of course I say fastest **reasonable** solution since sometimes a fast solution can be convoluted. Fortunately [a fast solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366910/128511) is pretty basic code.

Comment: `index` is traditionally abbreviated to `i`, not to `ndx`.

Comment: Building an intermediary array rather that the resulting object directly is rather inefficient

Comment: multiple separate answers by the same user are a normal feature of S.O. The answers are different so they are separate answers. The feature would not exist if this wasn't how it's supposed to work.

Comment: I think it would only make sense if I combine that and the reduce version in one answer. Otherwise your comment that fromEntries is referenced doesn't make any sense as it holds for reduce as well. I think for now I'll leave it.